# "Cannot cast from integer to double" error when running an example on Castalia3.3 using Omnet 5.3

Tags: casting, omnet++

When I run any example of Castalia 3.3 using Omnet5.3 on ubuntu, for example the connectivityMap one, I got this error:

"*Cannot evaluate parameter 'packetSpacing': (omnetpp::cIntParImpl)packetSpacing: Cannot cast from type integer to double -- in module (ConnectivityMap) SN.node[1].Application (id=25), at t=0.003536244016s, event #13*" .

When I looked at SensorNetwork.ned file, I found parameters that are of double type

parameters:

```
double field_x = default (30);          // the length of the deployment field
double field_y = default (30);          // the width of the deployment field
double field_z = default (0);           // the height of the deployment field (2-D field by default)

int numNodes;                       // the number of nodes

string deployment = default ("");

int numPhysicalProcesses = default (1);
string physicalProcessName = default ("CustomizablePhysicalProcess");
string wirelessChannelName = default ("WirelessChannel");
string debugInfoFileName = default ("Castalia-Trace.txt");
```

Is it a bug problem ? a parameter casting problem with the new version of omnet ? 
Help me please, I am not that expert with Omnet yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a bug, it is an intentional change since `OMNeT++ 5.3`.
The expression:

```
(double) par("packetSpacing")
```

results in calling `doubleValue()`. There is the following description of this method in `cPar.h`:

> Returns value as double. The cPar type must be DOUBLE.
>     Note: Implicit conversion from INT is intentionally missing.

---

There are two ways of resolving this issue:

1. Change the type of `packetSpacing` form `int` to `double` in `ConnectivityMap.ned`.

or

2. Force reading the parameter as `int` by adding `intValue()`, for example in `ConnectivityMap.cc`:

   ```
   packetSpacing = (double) par("packetSpacing").intValue() / 1000.0;
   ```